# The request was missing an Authentication Key with push notification in firebase

Tags: firebase, rest, postman

I'm trying to send a push notification via REST API Firebase by Postman for specific user I followed below request pattern:

POST request with below **URL** :

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send?key=**my Web API key**

and the **Body** is

{ "data":
{
"title": "Firebase notification",
"detail": "I am firebase notification. you can customise me. enjoy"
},
"to" : "**USER UID**"
}

but the problem is it returns  `The request was missing an Authentication Key.`

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow the steps as per bellow :

- API URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/
- Request Method Post
- Add 2 Key-value pairs in Header section like this

  ```
  Content-Type : application/json
  Authorization: key=[Your server key] (Make sure that no space allowed)
  ```
- For body choose raw data (JSON)

  ```
    { "data": { "title": "Firebase notification", "detail": "I am firebase notification. you can customise me. enjoy" }, "to" : "USER UID" }
  ```

Comment: but show me this A valid push subscription endpoint should be specified in the URL as such

Comment: the request does not pass until I added the project_id also .

Comment: I can not get your point of above comment. Please describe

Comment: There no requirement of project_id server key is sufficient

Comment: You can use the body like this

{
  "notification": {
    "body": "this is a body",
    "title": "this is a title"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "body": "this is a body",
    "title": "this is a title",
    "status": "done"
  },
  "registration_ids": [
    "device_fcm_token"
  ]
}